# Prove $S_d =\frac{2\pi^{\frac{d}{2}}} {\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})}$ where $S_d$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in d dimensions.

Tags: integration

Source:Exercise 1.1 from *Neural Network for Pattern Recognition by Bishop(1995 version)*

Show
$S_d =\frac{2\pi^{0.5d}} {\Gamma(0.5d)}$

( $S_d$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in $d$ dimensions.)
by making use of these.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(-\frac{\lambda}{2}x^{2})dx=(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda})^{0.5}$

$\prod_{i=1}^{d} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(-x_{i}^{2})dx_{i}=S_d\int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-r^2}\times r^{d-1}) dr$

$\Gamma(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{x-1} e^{-u} du$

I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: All formulas needed are "these" really?

Comment: According to the books, Yes.

Comment: Then these are found before 80s, 90s, before the invention of internet and you like studying maths from books. Too class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the second formula and divide both sides by the integral on the right hand side. Now you have a formula for $S_d$.

The first part of that formula is  a product of $d$ numbers, all of which are the same number and are given by the first formula (put $\lambda = 2$ in it).

The second part of that formula is an integral. Substitute $u=2r$ in that integral and use the third formula to express it in terms of the gamma function.